# What is the maximum number of operations the inbox can contain?

Tags: smart-rollup, rollup, scoru

What is the maximum number of operations the inbox can contain?

Question from Pierre-Louis from Slack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit in the maximum number of messages in the inbox. It is implemented with nested logarithmic data structure. It should be resilient to a lot of messages and inbox levels.

But we do have a limit per inbox level: it's technically 1 million messages.
In reality I'm not sure the L1 is able to process 1 million internal and/or external messages per block.
It's either we reach the size's limit with external messages that are included in blocks, or with internal messages that are only in the receipts IIUC. In this last case, you need to compute the minimal gas required for the internal message, and divide/multiply by the maximum amount of gas per block. The same can be done for external messages but IIRC the size's limit is more restraining than the gas.

In fact, the limitation of 1 million messages is a security protection, to ensure that proving the inclusion of a message in the inbox is relatively small.